# Glyphicon on dynamic button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm trying to add a glyphicon to my dynamically created button in my javascript file.
I can add it in the actual html file but I can't figure out how to add it from javascript

```
function createRemoveIcon(){
    var icon = document.createElement("span");

    icon.className ="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle";

    alert("test" + icon);
}
```

Or this is how I was originally trying to create it

```
function createRemoveRowButton(attendeeArrayIndex) {
    var removeIcon = document.getElementById("removeIcon");

    var removeRowButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var icon = document.createTextNode(removeIcon);
    removeRowButton.appendChild(icon);
    removeRowButton.onclick = function() {
        deleteRow(attendeeArrayIndex);
    };
    return removeRowButton;
}
```

Comment: A jsfiddle link would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your problem correctly. You want to add a button via javascript and then add an icon to that button.

This example adds a button to the DOM and when you click the button; it appends the icon to itself.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e9f2M/1/

```
function createRemoveIcon(){
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-default');
    button.innerHTML = 'click me';
    button.onclick = function(){ 
        var icon = document.createElement("span");

        icon.className ="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle";
        this.appendChild(icon);
    }
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            var p=document.createElement("p")
          var ActiveBtn = document.createElement("button");  
          var sp1 = document.createElement("span");

           sp1.style.color = "green";
           sp1.setAttribute("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-off");
           sp1.setAttribute("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle");
            ActiveBtn.appendChild(sp1);
```

p.appendChild(ActiveBtn)

Comment: Mind to explain your solution a bit?